# Yum dependency being provided by incorrect version

Tags: yum, rpm

Can someone explain what's going on here?

```
$ yum deplist institutional_sync-11.3.0-snap20191023.1247.202a207
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, changelog, security
Finding dependencies:
package: institutional_sync.noarch 11.3.0-snap20191023.1247.202a207
  dependency: sqlcipher = 4.2.0-1
   provider: sqlcipher.x86_64 4.0.1-4
   provider: sqlcipher.x86_64 4.2.0-1
   provider: sqlcipher.x86_64 4.0.1-4
   provider: sqlcipher.x86_64 4.0.1-2
   provider: sqlcipher.x86_64 4.0.1-3
   provider: sqlcipher.x86_64 4.0.1-4
```

the `sqlcipher` is an RPM I created using `fpm` from upstream [sqlcipher](https://www.zetetic.net/sqlcipher/) sources. Let me know if you need info on the `sqlcipher` RPM

```
$ rpm --provides -qp sqlcipher-4.2.0-1.x86_64.rpm
sqlcipher
sqlcipher = 4.2.0-1
sqlcipher(x86-64) = 4.2.0-1
```

Comment: can you `rpm -q --qf '%{epoch}:%{name}-%{version}-%{release}.%{arch}\n'` *package-name* and `-p` *package-file* for each of these?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think I figured it out. The `sqlcipher` in the `provides` list means it will provide any version I guess. This was my error when building with RPM, I specified `--provides sqlcipher`